# How to add multiple images in rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add several images to my site and am not quite sure how the routing works.

Here is my index.html.erb page

```
<%= render 'pages/home' unless user_signed_in? %>

<div id="properties" class="transitions-enabled">
    <% @properties.each do |property| %>


    <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <%= link_to image_tag(property.image.url(:medium)), property_path(property) %>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <%= property.description %><br>
            <strong><%= property.user.name if property.user %></strong>

            <!-- <% if property.user == current_user %>
                <div class="actions">
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_property_path(property) %>
                    <%= link_to 'Destroy', property, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                </div> -->
            <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And I think it's after this line `<%= link_to image_tag(property.image.url(:medium)), property_path(property) %>`  that I want to add another image.

Here is my _formfield.html.erb file where I ask for two images

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :street_image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :street_image, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

How do I show the :streetimage properly?

And this is my property model:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300", :thumb => "100x100"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]


    validates :image, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
end
```

And here's my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150429054455) do

  create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "street"
    t.integer  "zip"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "company"
    t.string   "city"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.integer  "space"
    t.string   "street_image_file_name"
    t.string   "street_image_content_type"
    t.integer  "street_image_file_size"
    t.datetime "street_image_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "properties", ["user_id"], name: "index_properties_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Why isnt <%= link_to image_tag(property.streetimage(:medium)), property_path(property) %> working. What error do you get

Comment: I get, undefined method `streetimage' for #<Property:0x007fc37d8613a0>

Comment: is streetimage a column in your Property table

Comment: what gem are you using for image uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.  Looks like I had the wrong variable set and didn't run rake db:migrate before